# Accessing ng-model from nested templates generated by ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble accessing values from an `ng-repeat` directive inside a nested template. Hope I'm using the right terminology, but here's some code that may make it clearer.

**outer-template.html**

```
  <div ng-repeat="test in $ctrl.test_list">
    <div id="test-{{ $index }}" layout="row">
      <inner-thing ng-model="test"></inner-thing>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**inner-template.html**

```
<div>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>ID</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test.id">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```

This is what I was hoping would work. The reasons it doesn't seem fairly obvious even to me, but I'm wondering if something like this is possible. I'm already aware that I can, from the 2nd (inner) controller, access each `test` using `$scope.parent.test_list`, but what I really want is for the 2nd (inner) template to be aware of which `test` it was "given" from the `ng-repeat` directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well in case anyone has this same question, the answer is quite simple:

**inner-template.html**

```
<div>
  <md-input-container>
    <label>ID</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="$parent.test.id">
  </md-input-container>
</div>
```